Reversed F Notation - Is this a typo?

A friend of mine asked me what this reversed F notation meant, and I can't find what it means. The Korean "증명" means "proof" and this notation is almost everywhere in the book (according to him) without additional explanation of the notation. Does this mean "forall" or something like that? Or is it just a typo?

Looks like a $\exists$ (existential quantifier, "there exists") with the bottom horizontal bar hidden, but it's hard to say without seeing more of the question and I can't explain the small $\forall$ . Would that make sense in context?

Do you have a picture of the whole page for context?

Or maybe you have the Korean name of the book?

That means 'for all.' I think reversed F stands to 'for,' and $\forall$ stands to 'all.'
